# jquery multi checkbox filter

Tags: jquery, filter, checkbox

I am trying to get a page to filter based on different parameters on the page for an accommodation section. I can't get the filters to work together though so that if the user clicks one section it will work with the other.

The fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/YEtgM/2/

thanks for any help

```
$('input').change(function(){
$('input').each(function(){
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked') || false;
    var numberofrooms = $(this).data('bedrooms');
    var sitelocation = $(this).data('location');
    $('li').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data('bedrooms')==numberofrooms){
            checked ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        }

        if ($(this).data('location')==sitelocation){
            checked ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        }

    });
});
```

});

Comment: Any reason why your inputs don't have name and value attributes?

Comment: no reason, this is just in test until it works and then I will add them in

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YEtgM/5/)**?

I gave your inputs values for a few reasons, but here's the jQuery:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var room_array = new Array(),
        loc_array = new Array();
    $('.br').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            room_array.push($(this).data('bedrooms'));
        }
    });
    $('.loc').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            loc_array.push($(this).data('location'));
        }
    });
    $('li').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 && $.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: thanks for that it is really helpful, however I probably wasn't too clear before, what I need is for the different datasets to work independently too.  so if a user clicks London they see all london and then it would filter down again on the different dataset when the user clicks 2 rooms so it shows just london 2 rooms.  I will be using a number of different datasets

Thanks